# db.execute does not return appropiate data. Error trying to access data

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table called 'transactions'. I want to get from that table my column 'shares' with some conditions. So i do the following:

```
 available_shares = db.execute("SELECT SUM(shares) as total_shares FROM transactions WHERE id = :id and stock = :symbol GROUP BY stock",
                                        id=session["user_id"], symbol=request.form.get("symbol"))
```

In order to see if this code works properly, i got to sqlite 3, and in my command line argument i type the following:

```
SELECT SUM(shares) as total_shares FROM transactions WHERE id=8 AND stock= "AAPL" GROUP BY stock;
```

And it returns the correct code that is:

```
total_shares
0
```

The problem comes when i want to delete a row from my transactions table if 'total_shares' equals 0. In order to do this i do the following(it doesnt work by the way):

```
if available_shares[0]["total_shares"] == 0:
            db.execute("DELETE FROM transactions WHERE id=:id AND stock=:symbol", id=session["user_id"], symbol=request.form.get("symbol"))
```

I cant figure out why when i run the program the row is still there, as if the program didnt recognize that condition, so it does not delete anything. Can someone help me please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Mind sharing that transactions table's schema?

Answer (score 0):

When you use SUM(shares) you are actually adding up columns together if i'm not mistaken.

So lets say you have the following data: 
id. sym. #. 
1. FB. 1. 
2. DOW. 3. 
3. DOW. 3. 
4. FB. -1.

If you select the SUM(shares of FB you will get 0 however that is coming from the addition of column 1 and 4.

If you want to delete column 1 and for you could try to DELETE WHERE symbol = FB.